# Server/Laravel 5.1 - Mail storage?

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So I developed an application with laravel and everything is running fine. I had mail as my mail driver but my server was misconfigured, or let's say, postfix was not installed. So the mail a user sent via contact form in my laravel app never got sent. Laravel never complained so I didn't even see any errors in the logs.

My question is: Did laravel or my server save the mail it tried to send anywhere so I could see what the user tried to send me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've somehow manually added mail logging, this won't be logged for you to send later.

Laravel's Mail functionality does include a **Log driver**, so that mail writes to a log- but this does not work in tandem with the other drivers, so you likely have zero logs currently.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#mail-and-local-development

There are also several results in google on how to implement global logging for all mail sent, maybe check out [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/2m2qal/trackinglogging_all_sent_mail/) or look into laravel events.